# how to set value in perl using system cmd

Tags: perl

we can set value in batch file in order to achieve same thing in Perl using system cmd 
i am facing problem with below piece of code.
already tried command:

```
system("(set a=10) & echo %a%");
```

I am expecting vale 10 to be printed.

Comment: In general, child processes can't change the environment of parent processes. I.e. a Perl script can't alter the environment of the invoking shell, and the shell spawned by `system` can't change the environment of the Perl script.

Comment: Could you please add punctuation and capitalize the first letter of your sentences? Then maybe even mere mortals like me could understand your question...

Comment: I do not see a question

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about Windows batch files. But from googling: if you put your commands in a batch file `cmd.bat`:

```
@echo off
set a=10
echo %a%
```

and then from perl script do

```
system('cmd.bat');
```

Or maybe this is not what you are looking for?